# Dragging in recyclerview is not working but swiping is?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, itemtouchhelper

I'm trying to get the dragging function to work on my `recyclerView` but only the swiping works at the moment.

I only have the basic code which as far as I understand should enable the action

```
ItemTouchHelper helper = new ItemTouchHelper(new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(ItemTouchHelper.UP | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN,
                ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
            @Override
            public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder dragged, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {


                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {

            }
        });
        helper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
```

And this code relates to the .XML file below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:clickable="true">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/historyView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        /> </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

It such a simple thing that I'm very confused as to why it wouldn't be working since the swiping works flawlessly. I can't seem to find anyone else who stumbled upon the same issue.

Comment: Put the recyclerview in a scrollview

Comment: This did not seem to work. No noticeable change

Comment: As far as i know to enable drag mode you need to do a long tap and then move. Also in onMove() method you have to change positions in adapter's data list and return true

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
@Override
public int getSwipeDirs(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
    if (viewHolder instanceof CartAdapter.MyViewHolder) return 0;
    return super.getSwipeDirs(recyclerView, viewHolder);
}
```